# How to do load-testing for 100 concurrent users login with unique username and passwords using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

My test plan scenario is to do load-testing for 100 concurrent users login to website.

I have created Threadgroup with Number of threads as 100.
Created CSV file which contains 100 users login details (unique usernames and passwords).
Under Sign in sample added a “User Parameter” from Thread Group -> PreProcessors to it. Added variables using __CSVRead function which reads values from file test.csv.
Selected the login sample and changed the values of userid and password to ${A} and ${B}.

Is this the right way to do or is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If this works for you and works as you expect, that's enough.

But looks like [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is more suitable and easier to use for multi-user scenarios than [__CSVRead function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead):

```
Thread Group
Number of Threads: N    // count of your test-threads (users)
Loop Count: 1
    CSV Data Set Config
    Filename: [path to your csv-file with usernames / passwords]
    Variable Names: username,pwd    // extracted values can be referred as ${username}, ${pwd}
    Recycle on EOF? False
    Stop thread on EOF? True
    Sharing mode: Current thread group
    . . .
    HTTP Request // your http call
    . . .
```

As per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead):

> The function is not suitable for use with large files, as the entire
>   file is stored in memory. For larger files, use CSV Data Set Config
>   element or StringFromFile.

Pretty detailed guides available here:

- [How to use a CSV file with JMeter](http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/)
- [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)